# Convert Numeric to Date in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is already a Datecolumn in Table which is in Numeric DataType(Converted to Int for faster ODBC Transfer), How can i convert that number to Data again?

Example the Values are like

```
42508
42826
43191
42158
42527
```

Which are nothing but like

```
SELECT CONVERT(numeric, getdate())
```

Query Result

```
43571
```

Just want to know how can i convert back that to normal date ?

Comment: What should be the date value for all these integer values? What were the original date value before you converted them to integer?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It was already created by some other guy, got no idea from what the actual value was..but seems like the example above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use next conversion:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, DATEADD(day, 43570, 0))
```

which will output:

```
17/04/2019 00:00:00
```

In this case SQL Server will use [implicit data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017), because [DATEADD()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) allows `datetime` datatype as third parameter and `DATEADD()` will convert `0` to `1900-01-01`.